# How to retrieve session information and pass single digit value in JMeter

Tags: json, session, xpath, jmeter, java-me

I have the below response on JMeter 5.2.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>

                <script id="web.layout.odooscript" type="text/javascript">
                    var odoo = {
                        csrf_token: "123123..",
                        debug: "",
                    };
                </script>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#875A7B"/>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    xx.__session_info__ = {**"uid": 2,** "is_system": true, "is_admin": true, "user_context": {"lang": "en_US", "uid": 2}, "db": "test", "server_version_info": [1, 0, 0, "final", 0, "e"], "support_url": "https://www.test.com", "name": "admin", **"username": "admin"**, "partner_id": 1 };
                </script>                
                <script type="text/javascript" ...></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" ...></script>
            </head>
            <body class="o_web_client">
            </body>
        </html>
```

I want to retrieve the "uid" and "username" values and pass them to the next request as a variable dynamically(uid value is 2 and username is admin)

Kindly suggest how to retrieve these values.

In addition, the uid value is very small and it's too complicated to find and replace so kindly suggest how to replace the existing id with the newly found id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing it in 2 steps:

1. Use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) to get the value of `xx.__session_info__`. Example configuration:

   [image]
2. Use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) to extract `uid` and `name` from the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) generated by the Boundary Extractor:

   [image]

End to end demo:

[image]